# jQuery only toggle this element

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#communities .inventory-search button.dropdown-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(".inventory-search .dropdown-toggle img").toggle();
});
```

This works, but it keeps toggling all the `.dropdown-toggle` img items, how do I just target the one that was clicked?

Comment: Without seeing your HTML its hard to answer but you want to do something like this `$(this).find(".inventory-search .dropdown-toggle img").toggle();`. Assuming what you are toggling is a child of the clicked element.

Comment: 'this' does wonder in JavaScript.

Comment: `this` is all that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` instead to refer to the current clicked element like:

```
$("img", this).toggle();
//Or
$(this).find("img").toggle();
```

Else all the images inside `.dropdown-toggle` will be toggled on click not just the clicked one, full code will be :

```
$("#communities .inventory-search button.dropdown-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $("img", this).toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
$("#communities .inventory-search button.dropdown-toggle").on("click", function () {
   $(this).find("img").toggle();
});
```

Comment: OP stated that they want to toggle the `.dropdown-toggle img` element. Your code would toggle the `.dropdown-toggle`, not the descendant image.

Comment: Oups, didn't notice that detail. Should be fixed now